# Maximizing a functional and related integral equation

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

The following functional
$$ J[F]:=\int_0^\infty dF(x_1)\int_0^\infty dF(x_2) \sqrt{1+\frac{x_1}{a+x_2}} $$
must be maximized with respect to $F$, which is supposed to be the probability distribution of a random variable with mean $\mu$. Assume $a>0$.

My approach is to compute the first variation of the Lagrangian 
$$
J[F]-\lambda_1 \left( \int_0^\infty dF(x_1)-1 \right)-\lambda_2 \left( \int_0^\infty dF(x_1) x_1 - \mu \right)
$$
and the problem reduces to finding the solution of the integral equation
$$
C_0+C_1 z = \int_0^\infty dF(x) \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{z}{a+x}} -\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{a+z}} \right)
$$
for some $C_0$ and $C_1$.

Problem is: How to find the solution of this integral equation? Any hint is welcome on this or related problem.

Comment: Where does this problem arise?

Comment: This is a generalization of the case without $x_2$, i.e.  $$ J[F]:=\int_0^\infty dF(x_1) \sqrt{1+x_1} $$, which I can solve following the same steps as above because instead of the integral equation there is an algebraic equation.